# Event ID 5586, error seems related to search

Tags: 2013, search, sql

The following error is being thrown every few minutes 24/7:

```
Unknown SQL Exception 201 occurred. Additional error information from SQL Server is included below.

Procedure or function 'prc_InsertSearch_CrawlDocumentStats' expects parameter '@BytesIndexableProperties', which was not supplied.
```

I have verified SQL Server is healthy and configured correctly. Search seems to be working correctly as well.

**EDIT #1**

Farm is SharePoint 2013, v15.0.4719.1000

**EDIT #2**

The full error message as found in the ULS:

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Procedure or function 'prc_InsertSearch_CrawlDocumentStats' expects parameter '@BytesIndexableProperties', which was not supplied.    
 at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)    
 at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)    
 at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)    
 at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString)    
 at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, SqlDataReader ds)    
 at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite)    
 at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe, Int32 timeout, Boolean asyncWrite)    
 at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SqlSession.ExecuteNonQuery(SqlCommand command)  ClientConnectionId:84b1ba3e-bb30-4fcb-a1fa-a6939e38a39a  Error Number:201,State:4,Class:16
```

Another error message within the ULS:

```
OpenQuery Failed with status ID: 0xc0000bb8. QueryPath: \Search Gatherer Content Plugin - SharePointServerSearch
```

However research indicates starting the `Usage and Health Data Collection Proxy` and doing an index reset should fix this issue, and may be unrelated. The `Usage and Health Data Collection Proxy` is already started.

Comment: You have to give more information about the error, what sharepoint version and what is build or cu level is? do u have blob cache? onw hat action this error occured

Comment: @WaqasSarwarMCSE I have added the version of the farm, and is the first line where I say "The following error is being thrown every few minutes 24/7" clear? It's not on an action, but by the context I'm assuming the search crawler throws it.

Comment: I suggest looking in the ULS logs around the time the event gets logged to see if there is any other supporting evidence to the cause of the issue. Do a Merge-SPLogFile for a few minutes before and after the time in the event and then search the outputted log for the error from the event.

Comment: @meany Have you found the root cause of this issue I am facing the same problem.

Comment: no @MarekSarad, I believe they just let it continue to error.